# Integrating ejabberd in to existing nodejs app using Bosch and Strophe

Tags: android, ios, node.js, ejabberd, strophe

I'm trying to integrate chat functionality and features in to existing node.js app (Expressjs) that is consumed by the native mobile apps (iOS and Android). One way is to use socket.io and provide chat functionality but ejabberd is obviously with more chat features such as group chat and so on.  So, my question is if all the business logic, user registration and authentication is within node.js app, how can I connect or integrate to ejabberd server. The mobile clients will use RESTful APIs to connect to the nodejs app server.

1. How to connect two servers and how to exchange info? IS it Strophe.js? didn't find a reputable npm library.
2. Do mobile clients needs to connect to both servers? meaning nodejs for user login, etc. and ejabberd for actual chat conversations?

Any help appreciated it - I'm installing the servers and trying to integrate them...

Thanks!

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You likely will use backend link between ejabberd and NodeJS, not XMPP directly. You have many options: ejabberd custom module, ejabberd XMLRPC API, Database sharing are example of possible approaches.

Comment: ok - I started looking in to this - @mickaël what do you recommend in terms of the link between nodejs app server and ejabbed server? here's what I think:
(1) iOS & android apps use xmpp lib to connect directly to ejabberd server
(2) App server (nodejs) connects to clients over RESTful to do user registration & login
(3) App server also connects to ejabberd server using what protocol? or library? this is what's not clear to me - what's the easiest option here?
Essentially what the App server needs to do is read the contents of the chat messages as well as handle all the business logic.Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid that if you want to deal with business logic, the best approach is to implement ejabberd plugins.